# adding listner to navigation drawer, menu item is not working

Tags: java, android

i am trying to add listner to my navigation drawer menu item but it's not working please check my script and also check this image [https://www.dropbox.com/s/imzufywwj5qyjlj/Nav_Menu.png?dl=0] Thank You.

ProfileActivity.java

```js
NavigationView navigationView =(NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        TextView prousername = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.pro_username);
        TextView promail = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.pro_mail);
        TextView prophone = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.pro_phone);

        ProDrawareLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_profile);
        ProToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,ProDrawareLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);

        ProDrawareLayout.addDrawerListener(ProToggle);
        ProToggle.syncState();

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        prousername.setText(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getUsername());
        promail.setText(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getUserEmail());
        prophone.setText(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).getUserPhone());

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                Switch(item.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.nav_logout:
                        SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).logOut();
                        finish();
                        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
                }
```

Navigation_menu.xml

```js
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_account"
            android:title="My account"/>

        <item android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
            android:title="Settings"/>

        <item android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
            android:title="Log Out"/>
    </group>

    <item android:title="Communicate">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/Rate_id"
                android:title="@string/rate_us"
                android:showAsAction="never"></item>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/Contact_id"
                android:title="@string/contact_us"
                android:showAsAction="never"></item>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/About_id"
                android:title="@string/about_us"
                android:showAsAction="never"></item>
        </menu>
    </item>
```

activity_profile.xml

```js
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/colorBG"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view" >

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Comment: Have you solved your issue ?

Comment: you are missing return value in switch case after case: `return true;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the upper case on your switch case function.

`switch` instead of `Switch`

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                Switch(item.getItemId()){  // the issue is here
                    case R.id.nav_logout:
                        SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).logOut();
                        finish();
                        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
                }
```

EDIT:

You can't use `this` like a reference to your activity because your are in this case in a `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`.

Try that instead :

Create a class field `private Context mContext`.
Instanciate `mContext` on `onCreate` function : `mContext = this`;
Use `mContext`.

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    Switch(item.getItemId()){  // the issue is here
                        case R.id.nav_logout:
                            SharedPrefManager.getInstance(mContext).logOut();
                            finish();
                            startActivity(new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class));
                    }
```

Comment: bro. still i am getting error on line ".getinstance(this)"  and (this, MainActivity.class)) please check this image [https://www.dropbox.com/s/u9cyxmvi9rmghyt/Nav_Menu2.png?dl=0]

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. i was just getting mad for it from yesterday. thank you so much. can i ask you one more question?

Comment: If this  answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark and doing a up vote. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution.  There is no obligation to do this.

If it's a new issue you may consider open a new topic, if is not yes of course you can ask a question :)

Comment: In my application header I have created 3 text View to retrieve data from my mysql database... two of them is workling fine but the "phone" it's for phone no. and it's not displaying anything. i've checked my .php files using postman and it's working fine.

Comment: In this case you must open a new post and expose your problem with some code , it's not unfortunately related to this issue.

Comment: @coachi... Thanks :)